# Application Idle - Is this thread-safe?

Tags: .net, vb.net, thread-safety

This should be thread-safe, am I right? Is there maybe a better way?

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class ApplicationIdleHelper
    Private Shared lastInputTicks As Long

    Public Shared Sub SetLastInputTime(dt As DateTime)
        Interlocked.Exchange(lastInputTicks, dt.Ticks)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetIdleTime() As Integer
        Return (Now - New DateTime(Interlocked.Read(lastInputTicks))).TotalSeconds
    End Function
End Class
```

In my application I'm setting the `lastInputTicks` value with the method `SetLastInputTime` in the `PreFilterMessage` event. In some other `Threads` I have to check this variable. I do this by calling `GetIdleTime`, but now I'm not sure, if this is thread-safe or I can get in trouble.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks okay. All access to the variable in question is covered by `Interlocked` so the access should be fine and you don't receive any corrupted values in your `GetIdleTime` function.

The only thing you should be aware of is that you may receive the *old* value from the `GetIdleTime` function because the exchange with the new value is not done. So if `SetLastInputTime` and `GetIdleTime` are called more or less at the same time, the `GetIdleTime` function may or may not show the updated time.

In any case I do not think that there is a way to get it done better than this. The overlapping call issue is something you never get rid of. That just is the nature of multi-threading.